# error al subir con fread

Tags: r

Al final de la última variable existe texto extra y no sube el archivo, se presenta el siguiente error:

> Expecting 26 cols, but line 15475 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having embedded sep='    ' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.

A modo de ejemplo agrego un archivo CSV que genera un error similar

```
Name,Company,Serving,Calories,Fat,Sodium,Carbs,Fiber,Sugars,Protein
AppleJacks,K,1,117,0.6,143,27,0.5,15,1
Boo Berry,G,1,118,0.8,211,27,0.1,14,1
Cap'n Crunch,Q,0.75,144,2.1,269,31,1.1,16,1.3
Cinnamon Toast, Crunch,G,0.75,169,4.4,408,32,1.7,13.3,2.7
```

Y la carga la realizamos mediante:

```
df <- fread(file="test.csv")
```

Comment: El error es bastante simple, el archivo que intentas leer no tiene un formato consistente en todas sus líneas, deberías subir de alguna forma el archivo de ejemplo, o al menos la línea 15475 como para que podamos hacer un diagnóstico más certero.

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante claro, se esta intentando cargar una archivo de valores separados por comas dónde hay al menos un registro que no respeta la misma cantidad de columnas que el resto. Esto puede deberse a que existan textos que incluyen `,` en los mismos, lo que sería eventualmente interpretado como un campo nuevo. La `,` muchas veces no es un buen separador, es preferible usar otro caracter como el pipe `|` siempre que podamos controlar la escritura.

[fread](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/fread) es una función muy flexible y óptima para importar datos desde una archivo delimitado por algún caracter. En tu caso, ya el error menciona una útil manera de, al menos, revisar dónde está el problema, que es mediante el parámetro: `fill=TRUE`, veamos:

```
library("data.table")
df <- fread(file="test.csv", fill=TRUE)
df
```

Y ahora podemos ver mejor el problema:

```
             Name Company Serving Calories   Fat Sodium Carbs Fiber Sugars Protein V11
1:     AppleJacks       K       1   117.00   0.6  143.0    27   0.5   15.0     1.0  NA
2:      Boo Berry       G       1   118.00   0.8  211.0    27   0.1   14.0     1.0  NA
3:   Cap'n Crunch       Q    0.75   144.00   2.1  269.0    31   1.1   16.0     1.3  NA
4: Cinnamon Toast  Crunch       G     0.75 169.0    4.4   408  32.0    1.7    13.3 2.7
5:                                      NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA      NA  NA
```

Si vemos la fila 4 podemos deducir que el texto de la columna `"Name"` debe ser `"Cinnamon Toast, Crunch"` y `"Crunch"` lo coloca en la segunda columna, viendo el desplazamiento de los datos es más sencillo darse cuenta.

Como regla generar al generar archivos delimitados y para no tener problemas posteriores, habría que contemplar:

- Usar un caracter no tan común como separador
- Usar el encomillado de campo texto, mediante: `fwrite(df, file="test.csv", quote=TRUE)`